# Given code base hosted on TFS, which command can tell me which file has changed most?

Tags: version-control, tfs, tfs-power-tools, tf-cli

I want to find out files under a given directory which have been updated most. Is there any command which can display this info? Or is there any way to get max version count for a given file, so I can write some script to get this info from all and then sort desc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean changed the most number of times, or undergone the most code chrun?

Either way - looking at the report data might be the easiest option for you.  Take a look at the following blog post I did explaining how to use Excel for looking at TFS data that uses churn as an example allowing you to drill down into folders and files - but you should be able to get the data that you are looking for.

- [Getting Started with the TFS Data Warehouse](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/getting_started.html)

Comment: yeah... I'm actually looking for file undergone most code chrun... thanks... will check out the blog.

Comment: I tried this, but I'm getting #N/A in all the columns for code churn count. Why is that? But I was able to pull out other information like changesets count etc. Any idea?